# Sum array values there key is the same

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am extracting some data from MySQL, then I am trying to sum up the values of the resulting array where the keys are the same. I have done this before just fine in this piece of code:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM comenzi";
        $result = $odb->query($q);

        $sumArr = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if ( !isset($sumArr[ $row['meniu_name'] ]) ) {
                $sumArr[ $row['meniu_name'] ] = $row['meniu_name'];
            }
            $sumArr[ $row['meniu_name'] ] += $row['cantitate'];
        }
        arsort($sumArr);
        $rowCount = 1;
        echo "<table><tr id='tableHeader'><td>#</td><td>produs</td><td>cantitate</td></tr>";
        foreach ($sumArr as $key => $value) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $rowCount . "</td><td>" . $key . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td></tr>";
            $rowCount++;
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

That is my working example, which brings us to my next one that is somewhat similar, yet for some reason it does not yield the required results:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM comenzi";
        $result = $odb->query($q);

        $sumArr = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if ( !isset($sumArr[ $row['utilizator'] ]) ) {
                // $sumArr[ $row['utilizator'] ] = $row['utilizator'];
            }
            $sumArr[ $row['utilizator'] ] += $row['cantitate'];
        }
        arsort($sumArr);
        print_r($sumArr);
        $rowCount = 1;
        echo "<table><tr id='tableHeader'><td>#</td><td>utilizator</td><td>cantitate produse</td></tr>";
        foreach ($sumArr as $k => $v) {

            $odb                =           new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db, $user, $pass);

            $stmtCheck  =       $odb->prepare('SELECT nume, prenume, email, telefon FROM utilizatori WHERE id=?');
            $stmtCheck->execute(array($k));
            $r = $stmtCheck->fetch();


            echo "<tr><td>" . $rowCount . "</td><td>" . "<b>nume: </b>" . $r[0] . "<b> prenume: </b>" . $r[1] . "<b> email: </b>" . $r[2] . "<b> telefon: </b>" . $r[3] . "</td><td>" . $v . "</td></tr>";
            $rowCount++;
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

What happens here, is quite dubious: the commented line `// $sumArr[ $row['utilizator'] ] = $row['utilizator'];`, if it is commented out I get the expected results, however having it commented out I get the errors:

> Notice: Undefined offset

If I do not comment that line I do not get the Undefined offset errors, but my values are ridiculous.

Correct values: `Array ( [22] => 19 [32] => 11 )`
Values with that line not commented out: `Array ( [32] => 43 [22] => 41 )`

I cannot even understand a mathematical way it gets to those values, can't find anything that could throw me the right direction, therefore I'm baffled.

Comment: Can't you just use  `array_sum($yourarray);` ?

Comment: hmm, let me look into that really quick. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: looked into it: array_sum sums all the values inside that array, i need them to be summed key specific. That is why i use arsort($sumArr);

Comment: Why dont you use mysql to sum the same products? Take a look at GROUP BY http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php It will save you a lot of code!

Comment: @iffy: I apologise for the sharp tone you experienced on one of the answers here. The comments have been moderated away - don't let it put you off asking or answering questions. There are a few individuals on this site who, for all their technical know-how, are imo best ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to initialize your entry to 0 :

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if(!isset($sumArr[ $row['utilizator'] ])) $sumArr[ $row['utilizator'] ] = 0;
    $sumArr[ $row['utilizator'] ] += $row['cantitate'];
}
```

The if line will create the `$row['utilizator']` entry in the `$sumArr` array and will initialize its value to 0.

The problem you had is that you initialized it with a string I think :

```
$sumArr[ $row['meniu_name'] ] = $row['meniu_name'];
```

IMO `$row['meniu_name']` is a string. Then, when you do addition on a string, PHP tends to convert this string into integer, which gives you weird results you noticed.

Comment: thanks mate. Much appreciated! if you could point me into the right direction to read around the subject so I understand why that is the case, would love long time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn SQL first: as the listing below illustrates, you can do all of this in one query, which is both simpler and more efficient than trying to drag down all of the data and *then* process it.

```
SELECT nume, prenume, email, telefon, utilizator, sum(cantitate) 
FROM comenzi, utilizatori WHERE id = utilizator GROUP BY utilizator
```